# Tkinter - Prevent children from changing parent width

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

By default, Tkinter widgets will resize based on their children's sizes (i.e., Tkinter will not respect my `width` and `height` configurations). I know that using `parent.pack_propagate(False)` will prevent `parent`'s children from modifying its dimensions, but what if I only want to prevent the children from changing one dimension, allowing it to modify another dimension? For example, how would I prevent a widget's children from modifying its width but allow it to change its height?

One hack-ish solution I came up with was to have a 1px tall frame with my requested width and add that to the parent, which prevented the other children from shrinking the width of the parent, but this seems like an inelegant solution. Is there any built-in solution to this?

Comment: You control which widgets go in the frane, why not just make sure the widgets are all the same width?

Comment: I want to have some padding between my widgets and the window edge. For example, making a button's width the same width as the window wouldn't look nice since there would be no padding.

Comment: so, make the buttons of width 1, then use grid or pack options to have them automatically expand, and include some padding.

Comment: If I set the padding, and then decrease the window width while the program is running, the button just disappears behind its own padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to constrain the geometry propagation in only one direction.

In my experience there are almost always better ways to solve layout problems than turning propagation off. There is no single best solution, it all depends on your specific layout needs.

Comment: Is my proposed solution (second paragraph of question) an acceptable solution or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Kootling: it's impossible to say. It depends on what your real problem is.